# Emacs Haskell Mode Flymake

Tags: haskell, emacs, flymake

I've been trying to get Flymake to work with Haskell mode in emacs. I've gotten this to work in the past and I have to say the combination of Flymake and Haskell's type system is ridiculously synergistic. Now it seems I am having trouble getting error/warning highlighting and all to work. I've tried ghc-mod and I've also followed some of the wikis. Please help, bonus if you can get it working with cabal-dev.

GHC-7.4 and GHC 7.0. 
Emacs 23.4.

Comment: We need more information.  Is this a new machine?  If not, what changed that broke?  Do you have haskell-mode installed? (because it's really hard to break its syntax highlighting)  Do you see an error? (check the *Messages* buffer)

Comment: Do you have it flymake working? If so let me know what version of GHC and Emacs you are using and other setup info.

Comment: GHC 7.0.X, Emacs 24.  I just followed the ghc-mod installation instructions.

Comment: When I run ghc-mod check from the command line it doesn't seem to respond with anything (even with a file that has errors). This could be the problem.

Comment: It should print out "ghc-mod version 0.6.1
Usage:" and a list of the options it supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Eric is right on target.  According to this: https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/issues/49
ghc-mod appears to work only with specific versions of GHC (7.0.4 seems to be a good choice)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following the steps described in this [blog post](http://sritchie.github.com/2011/09/25/haskell-in-emacs.html)?

They seem to use hs-lint with flymake to perform the syntactic checks. I'm not sure they support type errors reporting, though.